# Abrir links de iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, link, google

Como fazer para impedir que links de Iframe que tem a propriedade `target="_blank"` e abrir esses links em outro iframe só que na mesma página?

Exemplo:

Conteúdo do iframe1: `<a href="http://t.co/YJdEOEu8Dz" target="_blank">MEU VIDEO</a>`
Conteúdo do iframe2: `<span>Aqui será o link que foi clicado no iframe1<span>`

Comment: Esses iFrames estão no mesmo domínio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso... <strike>(mas terá de trocar `http://www.google.com.br` pois ele não vai carregar dentro do IFrame.)</strike>. Consegui achar uma URL do Google que funciona dentro do IFrame, só pra você poder conferir o funcionamento.

```js
$("body").on("click", "a", function(e) {
  var target = $(this).attr("target");
  if (target == '_blank') {
    $("#meuIFrame").attr('src', $(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search" target="_blank">Google</a>
</div>
<iframe id="meuIFrame" src="" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></iframe>
```

Tal como a URL `http://google.com.br` não funciona, qualquer URL cuja resposta contenha o cabeçalho [`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) também não vai abrir dentro do IFrame, a não ser que você tenha como colocar este HTML na mesma origem da URL.

Comment: sim os 2 iframe estão localizados na mesma página

Comment: tipo eu estou utilizando isso para executar um widget do twitter mas quando é clicado para Retwittar ou Curtir ele abre em nova página. por isso quero ter esses 2 iframe 1 com o twitter do usuário e o outro para abrir quando clicar nos links da postagem!

Comment: Mas só uma coisa... eu não quero abrir todos os links de target="_blank" não, apenas o que estão dentro do widget do twitter.

Comment: Nesse caso é só substituir o `"body"` por outro seletor que envolva apenas o widget desejado.